# How to read beyond new line characters using fgets() function?

Tags: c, fgets

I understand from C manpage that using `fgets()`, reading stops after an `EOF` or a newline. i have a program that reads from file(with multiple lines) and reading stop at the end of new line.

Is there a way to force`fgets()` to ignore newlines and read till `EOF`?

```
while(fgets(str,1000, file))
{ 
 // i do stuffs with str here
}
```

Comment: Would you consider using another function? Because as far as `fgets()` is concerned, it will stop once, it gets either a new-line character or an end-of-file.

Comment: @P.W: `getline` behaves like `fgets`, expect that it manages the memory for you. It won't solve the newline problem. (But `getdelim` with a null delimiter might work. Both are non-standard functions, though.)

Comment: `fgets` is not the only function that reads data from a file. If you want the entire file in memory, just `read` it in its entirety. (Best make sure you allocated enough memory.)

Comment: @MOehm:It was my mix up with the C++ `getline` where one can specify the delimiter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to force `fgets()` to ignore newlines and read till `EOF`?

No, you can't because `fgets()` is implemented in such a way that the parsing will stops if **end-of-file** occurs or a **newline character** is found. May you can consider using other file i/o function like [**`fread()`**](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fread).

Answer (score 1):

In the while loop you have to make the following check:

```
while ((fgets(line, sizeof (line), file)) != NULL)
```

On success, the function returns the same str parameter. If the End-of-File is encountered and no characters have been read, the contents of str remain unchanged and a null pointer is returned.
If an error occurs, a null pointer is returned.

code example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char *filename = "test.txt";
    char line[255];
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen(filename, "r");
    while ((fgets(line, sizeof (line), file)) != NULL) {
        printf("%s", line);
    }
    fclose(file);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thank, `fgets()` return `NULL` on` \n` or `EOF` so even on the snippet above `fgets()` stops at the first new line found.  @samuil

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/ from the reference fgets() will return NULL only if it reached the end of file or if some other error occurred. If it managed to read the line it will not return NULL. Maybe there is something wrong with the file your read from :) don't know

Answer (score 0):

NO, `fgets` stops reading after it encounters a \n (new line) character.

Otherwise, you must find and remove the newline yourself.

[Or you can use](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fread.htm) `fread`:

> The C library function size_t fread(void *ptr, size_t size, size_t
>   nmemb, FILE *stream) reads data from the given stream into the array
>   pointed to, by ptr.
>
> The total number of elements successfully read are returned as a
>   size_t object, which is an integral data type. If this number differs
>   from the nmemb parameter, then either an error had occurred or the End
>   Of File was reached.

```
/* fread example: read an entire file */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
  FILE * pFile;
  long lSize;
  char * buffer;
  size_t result;

  pFile = fopen ( "myfile.bin" , "rb" );
  if (pFile==NULL) {fputs ("File error",stderr); exit (1);}

  // obtain file size:
  fseek (pFile , 0 , SEEK_END);
  lSize = ftell (pFile);
  rewind (pFile);

  // allocate memory to contain the whole file:
  buffer = (char*) malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize);
  if (buffer == NULL) {fputs ("Memory error",stderr); exit (2);}

  // copy the file into the buffer:
  result = fread (buffer,1,lSize,pFile);
  if (result != lSize) {fputs ("Reading error",stderr); exit (3);}

  /* the whole file is now loaded in the memory buffer. */

  // terminate
  fclose (pFile);
  free (buffer);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Curios: Why `sizeof(char) *` in `malloc (sizeof(char)*lSize)`? versus just `buffer = malloc (lSize);`?